# What did Shimura say about $y^2 + y = x^3 - x$?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

From the introduction of Ribet-Stein:

> Shimura showed that if we start with the elliptic curve $E$ defined by the equation $y^2 +y = x^3 −x^2$ then for “most” $n$ the image of $\rho$ is all of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})$.

Here $\rho$ is the representation of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$ on the $n$-torsion of $E$.  What is the original paper where Shimura shows this?  (Is there an online copy?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Goro Shimura, A reciprocity law in non-solvable extensions. J. Reine Angew.  Math.  221 1966 209--220.

Comment: https://eudml.org/doc/150726

Comment: See also https://eudml.org/doc/142133 Propriétés galoisiennes des points d'ordre fini des courbes elliptiques.

Jean-Pierre Serre
Inventiones mathematicae (1971/72)
Volume: 15, page 259-331